# Creating Virtuallbox Disk in VM Folder with BASH

Tags: bash, virtualbox

I am attempting to write a bash script that allows me to create a Virtualbox VDI storage file in the folder where I have set up my VM. Here's the code that I have thus far:

```
vm="Windows 7"
vm_type=Windows7

VBoxManage createvm --name "${vm}" --ostype "${vm_type}" --register
VBoxManage modifyvm "${vm}" --memory 2048 --acpi on --boot1 dvd
VBoxManage modifyvm "${vm}" --nic1 bridged --bridgeadapter1 eth0
vm_dir = `VBoxManage showvminfo "${vm}" | grep "Config file"`
```

I am attempting to use the *Config file* string to retrieve the directory of the installed VM, trim the string down to just the VM directory and create the harddisk file there. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [VBoxManage documentation](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-showvminfo) gives the following example of the Config file line:

```
Config file:     /home/username/.VirtualBox/Machines/Windows XP/Windows XP.xml
```

Thus, if we alter your assigment of `vm_dir` to:

```
vm_dir=`VBoxManage showvminfo "${vm}" | grep "Config file"| cut -2 -d:`
```

we have the path of the config file. **NOTE**: Remove spaces from around the `=` as that is incorrect. To extract the directory portion of it, we'll use `dirname`:

```
vm_dir=`VBoxManage showvminfo "${vm}" | grep "Config file"| cut -2 -d:`
vm_dir=`dirname $vm_dir`
```

These 2 commands can obviously be combined in a nested fashion if we use `$(...)` for command substitution instead of ``` `` ```:

```
vm_dir="$(dirname $(VBoxManage showvminfo "${vm}" | grep "Config file"| cut -2 -d:))"
```

I'm also using `"..."` around the whole command substitution in case the path has whitespace in it.

Next, you can create the disk with [VBoxManage createhd](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-createvdi) by using the filename `"$vm_dir/name_of_your_choice.vdi"`.

Comment: Thanks @Samveen. That was very helpful. I was in Bangalore this time last year, so if I ever head there Bangalorean coffee (or _chai_, if that's what you prefer) is on me! :)